# Multiple joins and processing speed

Tags: sql, join

I am using multiple joins in a query. One join permits me to pick out the various category names I wish to sum over. The other join just adds meta-data to my query. For some reason when I add the last join my query slows way...down. I'm not sure what the issue is.

values_table contains the actual values that I want to sum over, it contains rows, run Id, values, date and category. The category table contains a list of the particular categories I want to sum over. The meta_table is a table of meta data for each run Id. I'm interested in picking out those run IDs that have the year=2018 and the month=12. For each year and month I have over  600 000 entries in my values_table.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [values_table].Row = [category_table].Row  THEN 
[values_table].Value ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Value',
[values_table].Date AS Date, [meta_table].metadata as metadata
FROM [values_table]
JOIN [category_table] 
ON [values_table].Row=[category_table].Row
AND [values_table].[Id] IN (SELECT [meta_table].[Id] FROM [values_table] 
WHERE
Year = 2018 AND Month = 12)
JOIN [meta_table]
ON [values_table].[Id] = [meta_table].[Id]
AND [meta_table].[Year]= 2018
AND [meta_table].[Month] = 12
GROUP BY [values_table].Date;
```

When I run this code without the last join it takes less than second, when I run it with the last join it takes... (not sure how long I stopped it after 6 minutes).

Comment: Do you have a query plan? You can use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to post it. This could be due to anything from bad indexes, to bad estimates, to just the sheer size of the tables.

Comment: Also, I would add the subquery
    AND [values_table].[Id] IN (SELECT [meta_table].[Id] FROM [values_table] 
into the WHERE clause

Comment: Could you write the modified code out? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.